Keep training pytorch model on new data
I'm working on a text classification task and have decided to use a PyTorch model for this purpose. The process mainly involves the following steps:

Load and process the text.
Use a TF-IDF Vectorizer.
Build the neural network and save the TF-IDF Vectorizer and model to predict new data.

However, every day I need to classify new comments and correct any wrong classifications.
Currently, my approach is to add the new comments with the correct classification to the dataset and retrain the entire model. This process is time-consuming, and the new comments can be lost during validation. I would like to create a new dataset with the newly classified texts and continue training over this new data (the new comments are classified manually, so each label is correct).
Using GPT and some online code, i write the desired process, however, im not sure if its working as expected, or im making some silly mistakes that should not happen.
So the mains questions are:

How could i check if the propossed way to solve this problem work as i expect?
What can i do with the vectorizer when it face new tokens, can i just do a .fit_transform() or i would loose the original vectorizer?

Here its the full training process:
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import polars as pl
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import joblib

set1 = (
    pl
    .read_csv(
        "set1.txt",
        separator=";",
        has_header=False,
        new_columns=["text","label"]
    )
)

# since the dateset its unbalanced, im going to force to have more balance

fear_df = set1.filter(pl.col("label") == "fear")
joy_df = set1.filter(pl.col("label") == "joy").sample(n=2500)
sadness_df = set1.filter(pl.col("label") == "sadness").sample(n=2500)
anger_df = set1.filter(pl.col("label") == "anger")

train_df = pl.concat([fear_df,joy_df,sadness_df,anger_df])

"""
The text its already clean, so im going to change the labels to numeric
and then split it on train, test ,val
"""

label_mapping = {
    "anger": 0,
    "fear": 1,
    "joy": 2,
    "sadness": 3
}

train_mapped = (
    train_df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("label").replace_strict(label_mapping, default="other").cast(pl.Int16)
    )
   
)

train_set, pre_Test = train_test_split(train_mapped,
                                    test_size=0.4,
                                    random_state=42,
                                    stratify=train_mapped["label"])

test_set, val_set = train_test_split(pre_Test,
                                    test_size=0.5,
                                    random_state=42,
                                    stratify=pre_Test["label"]) 

# Vectorize text data using TF-IDF
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=30000, ngram_range=(1, 2))

X_train_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set['text']).toarray()
X_val_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(val_set['text']).toarray()
X_test_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(test_set['text']).toarray()

y_train = train_set['label']
y_val = val_set['label']
y_test = test_set['label']

class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, texts, labels):
        self.texts = texts
        self.labels = labels
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.texts[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return text, label
    
train_dataset = TextDataset(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
val_dataset = TextDataset(X_val_tfidf, y_val)
test_dataset = TextDataset(X_test_tfidf, y_test)

batch_size = 32
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

class TextClassificationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_classes):
        super(TextClassificationModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 64)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x), dim=1)
        return x
    
input_dim = X_train_tfidf.shape[1]
model = TextClassificationModel(input_dim, 4)

# Define loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adamax(model.parameters())

# Training loop
num_epochs = 17
best_val_acc = 0.0
best_model_path = "modelbest.pth"

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for texts, labels in train_loader:
        texts, labels = texts.float(), labels.long()
        outputs = model(texts)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Validation
    model.eval()
    correct, total = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for texts, labels in val_loader:
            texts, labels = texts.float(), labels.long()
            outputs = model(texts)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    val_acc = correct / total
    if val_acc > best_val_acc:
        best_val_acc = val_acc
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), best_model_path)

    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, Val Acc: {val_acc:.4f}')

# Load the best model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(best_model_path))

# Load the best model
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(best_model_path))

# Test the model
model.eval()
correct, total = 0, 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for texts, labels in test_loader:
        texts, labels = texts.float(), labels.long()
        outputs = model(texts)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
test_acc = correct / total
print(f'Test Acc: {test_acc:.3f}')


# Save the TF-IDF vectorizer
vectorizer_path = "tfidf_vectorizer.pkl"
joblib.dump(vectorizer, vectorizer_path)

# Save the PyTorch model
model_path = "text_classification_model.pth"
torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_path)


Proposed code:
import torch
import joblib
import polars as pl
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

# Load the saved TF-IDF vectorizer
vectorizer_path = "tfidf_vectorizer.pkl"
vectorizer = joblib.load(vectorizer_path)

input_dim = len(vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())

class TextClassificationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_classes):
        super(TextClassificationModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 64)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(32, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x), dim=1)
        return x
    
# Load the saved PyTorch model
model_path = "text_classification_model.pth"
model = TextClassificationModel(input_dim, 4)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))

# Map labels to numeric values
label_mapping = {"anger": 0, "fear": 1, "joy": 2, "sadness": 3}
sentiments = ["fear","joy","sadness","anger"]

new_data = (
    pl
    .read_csv(
        "set2.txt",
        separator=";",
        has_header=False,
        new_columns=["text","label"]
    )
    .filter(pl.col("label").is_in(sentiments))
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("label").replace_strict(label_mapping, default="other").cast(pl.Int16)
    )
    
)
# Vectorize the new text data using the loaded TF-IDF vectorizer
X_new = vectorizer.transform(new_data['text']).toarray()
y_new = new_data['label']

class TextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, texts, labels):
        self.texts = texts
        self.labels = labels
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = self.texts[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return text, label

batch_size = 10
   
# Create DataLoader for the new training data
new_train_dataset = TextDataset(X_new, y_new)
new_train_loader = DataLoader(new_train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Define loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adamax(model.parameters())

num_epochs = 5
new_best_model_path = "modelbest.pth"
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    for texts, labels in new_train_loader:
        texts, labels = texts.float(), labels.long()
        outputs = model(texts)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), new_best_model_path)
        
print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

# Save the PyTorch model
new_best_model_path = "new_moedl.pth"
torch.save(model.state_dict(), new_best_model_path)

The dataset can be found here
